# Triginometric formula for calculating results of 2D elastic collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, geometry

I am trying to write a code that manages elastic collisions between two circles in 2D space but am failing to locate a working formula.

For the collision itself the known variables are:

- mass of both particles
- initial velocities of both particles
- initial movement angles for both particles
- contact angle

What I try to establish are the final velocities and movement angles of colliding particles.

According to my research, pretty much any source that attempts to solve this problem refers to the below formula available on Wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects))

\begin{align}
            v'_{1x}&=\frac{v_{1}\cos(\theta_1-\varphi)(m_1-m_2)+2m_2v_{2}\cos(\theta_2-\varphi)}{m_1+m_2}\cos(\varphi)
            \\[0.2em]
            &\quad+v_{1}\sin(\theta_1-\varphi)\cos(\varphi+\frac{\pi}{2})
            \\[0.8em]
            v'_{1y}&=\frac{v_{1}\cos(\theta_1-\varphi)(m_1-m_2)+2m_2v_{2}\cos(\theta_2-\varphi)}{m_1+m_2}\sin(\varphi)
            \\[0.2em]
            &\quad+v_{1}\sin(\theta_1-\varphi)\sin(\varphi+\frac{\pi}{2})
            \end{align}

The formula itself is taken from [this website](https://williamecraver.wixsite.com/elastic-equations). And has apparently already caused issues to users of this stack exchange previously ([a link to a previous question using this formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/elastic-ball-collision-and-contact-angle))

The issue that I have is that replicating this formula in my code does not always provide what appears to be a correct result, but it works as expected in some of the cases.

I was verifying the expected outcomes against the simulation available [here](http://www.sciencecalculators.org/mechanics/collisions/). The results produced by this simmulation differ from the ones produced by the formula, even though the same formula is also displayed on the website hosting the simulation.

My question is - is this formula actually correct and if it is not what would the correct formula look like? Also, I know it is possible to solve this with vectors, but I am looking for a trigonometric solution.

Thank you

---

UPD: some examples of issues

**Example 1** (appears to operate as expected):

m1 = 100; m2 = 10; v1 = 6; v2 = 1; angle1 = 0; angle2 = 0; contact_angle = 0

results given:

- v1x = 5.090909
- v1y = 0
- v2x = 10.09091
- v2y = 0

**Example 2** (appears to operate as expected):

m1 = 30; m2 = 20; v1 = 40; v2 = 50; angle1 = 315; angle2 = 135; contact_angle = -45

results given:

- v1x = -22.62742
- v1y = 22.62742
- v2x = 41.01219
- v2y = -41.01219

**Example 3** (appears to be wrong):

m1 = 10; m2 = 10; v1 = 6; v2 = 1; angle1 = 0; angle2 = 180; contact_angle = -45

results given:

- v1x = 2.581109
- v1y = -2.416636
- v2x = 2.486482
- v2y = -2.513894

Surely they cannot both go down post collision?

---

UPD2: Example 3 was produced by an incorrect code. My reply below includes a version that produces correct results

Comment: In what particular situations does it appear to not provide a correct result?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024) for typesetting mathematical expressions.

Comment: @probably_someone - I have added some examples in the descrition of the question

Comment: It would help if you showed the coordinate axes and how your angles are measured against those axes.

Comment: Just wondering why bother as one can just use vectors and $m_1\vec v_1+m_2\vec v_2=m_1\vec v_1^*+m_2\vec v_2^*$;$\frac 1 2m_1(\vec v_1)^2+\frac 1 2m_2(\vec v_2)^2=\frac 1 2m_1(\vec v_1^*)^2+\frac 1 2m_2(\vec v_2^*)^2$...

Comment: @user12986714 Those equations aren't enough to determine a unique scenario

Answer (score 1):

The formula appears to be correct or at least produces same results as the simmulation on "scincecalculators" ([link](http://www.sciencecalculators.org/mechanics/collisions/)) that I was using as a reference.

The issue in my Example 3 was due to coding error.

Here is a Python code that produces the correct results ([link to code snippet](https://trinket.io/python/9100ec49f6)), hopefully somebody will find this useful:

```
import math

mass1 = 10
mass2 = 10
velocity1 = 6
velocity2 = 1
angle1 = 0
angle2 = 180
contact_angle = -45
pi = math.pi

def final_vx(m1, m2, v1, v2, O1, O2, phi):
  numerator_p1 = v1 * math.cos((O1 - phi) * pi / 180) * (m1 - m2)
  numerator_p2 = 2 * m2 * v2 * math.cos((O2 - phi) * pi / 180)
  numerator = numerator_p1 + numerator_p2
  denominator = m1 + m2
  addition = v1 * math.sin((O1 - phi) * pi / 180) * math.cos((phi * pi / 180) + pi / 2)
  result = (numerator / denominator) * math.cos(phi * pi / 180) + addition

  return(result)


def final_vy(m1, m2, v1, v2, O1, O2, phi):
  numerator_p1 = v1 * math.cos((O1 - phi) * pi / 180) * (m1 - m2)
  numerator_p2 = 2 * m2 * v2 * math.cos((O2 - phi) * pi / 180)
  numerator = numerator_p1 + numerator_p2
  denominator = m1 + m2
  addition = v1 * math.sin((O1 - phi) * pi / 180) * math.sin((phi * pi / 180) + pi / 2)
  result = (numerator / denominator) * math.sin(phi * pi / 180) + addition

  return(result)

v1x = final_vx(mass1, mass2, velocity1, velocity2, angle1, angle2, contact_angle)
v1y = final_vy(mass1, mass2, velocity1, velocity2, angle1, angle2, contact_angle)
v2x = final_vx(mass2, mass1, velocity2, velocity1, angle2, angle1, contact_angle)
v2y = final_vy(mass2, mass1, velocity2, velocity1, angle2, angle1, contact_angle)
print("v1x = " + str(v1x))
print("v1y = " + str(v1y))
print("v2x = " + str(v2x))
print("v2y = " + str(v2y))
```